# EC2 How to open UDP Port 10000?

Tags: amazon-ec2, udp, port, firewall, iptables

I'm trying Wowza and am a bit confused why can't the port `10000` be opened on my EC2/RHEL instance.

I have already applied the required rule in the Security Group which is in used on that instance. Like:

[image]

As see above, i even opened for TCP. Then in the RHEL/EC2 instance,

[image]

However i started or stopped the `iptables`, nothing happened but **still being CLOSED**.

What went wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run

```
iptables save
```

to save the rules.

See my cheat sheet for other commands: http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/375-iptables-cheat-sheet